# single valued function in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let 
$$f(z)=\int_{1}^{z} \left(\frac{1}{w} + \frac{a}{w^3}\right)\cos(w)\,\mathrm{d}w$$
Find $a$ such that $f$ is a single valued function in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1w+\frac{a}{w^3}\right)\cos(w)
&=\left(\frac1w+\frac{a}{w^3}\right)\left(1-\frac12w^2+O\left(w^4\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{a}{w^3}+\color{#C00000}{\left(1-\frac12a\right)}\frac1w+O(w)
\end{align}
$$

The residue at $0$ is $1-\frac12a$, so setting $a=2$ gives a residue of $0$.

Comment: would you like to explain we why you conclude that yhe function in the integral must be analytic?

Comment: @YoshuaYonatan: that wasn't part of the question. 

The difference of the integral over any two paths is the integral around a contour which is the difference of the two paths. Since the residue at the only singularity is $0$, the integral over any closed contour is $0$. Thus, the integral is independent of the path chosen.

$f(z)$ is analytic since $f'(z)=\left(\frac1w+\frac{a}{w^3}\right)\cos(w)$.

Comment: Maybe you should remind the OP that the integral in defining $f$ needs modification. It cannot start from $0$, which is not well defined.

Comment: @Landscape: excellent point! I missed that. Heh, as soon as I posted a comment, the OP edited the question.

Comment: @landscape. Thanks. It start from 1.

Comment: @Robjohn. Thenks, I agree with the argument that the integral was independent of the path chosen. But, why the residue at 0 must be 0?

Comment: @YoshuaYonatan: if the residue at $0$ is not $0$, then the integral around a closed contour that circles the origin is $2\pi i$ times the residue. Then the integral over two paths whose difference is that closed contour differ by $2\pi i$ times the residue.

Comment: @Robjohn. Oh Isee. Thank You.

Comment: @YoshuaYonatan: You are welcome. Since you are new to this website, just in case, if you think robjohn's answer helpful, you may [accept it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/46120).